# Echo mix of HTML and PHP giving an error

Tags: php, html, wordpress, echo

I'm trying to echo this long statement, tried looking at other answers here, nothing is fixing it.

```
Error: 
Parse error: parse error, expecting `','' or `';'' 
Errors parsing -
```

.

```
<?php 

$videoEmbed = get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'ctslider_videoembedcode', true ); 
$postThumb = the_post_thumbnail();


echo '<div onclick="thevid=document.getElementById('thevideo'); thevid.style.display='block'; this.style.display='none'"><img src="'.echo $postThumb.'" style="cursor:pointer" /></div><div id="thevideo" style="display:none">"'.echo $videoEmbed.'"</div>';?>
```

Comment: Look at the highlighting in the code in your question :)

Comment: Escape the quotes (') with a backslash (\)

Comment: @andrewsi you mean the error? I can't see where I'm missing those though.

Comment: @StefanNeubert It appears you've done such a good job at escaping that apostrophe that it's not displaying :)

Comment: @robotturtle - you're using single quotes in your echo, to start and end it; you've also got them inside the contents, in your javascript. PHP is seeing the first single quote in `getElementById('thevideo')`, and parsing it as the end of your echo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to escape your '
So it gives:

```
echo '<div onclick="thevid=document.getElementById(\'thevideo\'); thevid.style.display=\'block\'; this.style.display=\'none\'"><img src="'.$postThumb.'" style="cursor:pointer" /></div><div id="thevideo" style="display:none">"'.$videoEmbed.'"</div>';
```

And you don't need echo inside the first echo

Answer (score 0):

Do you realy need to echo a div? 
Can't you do that :

```
<div onclick="thevid=document.getElementById('thevideo'); thevid.style.display='block'; this.style.display='none'"> 
    <img src="<?php echo $postThumb ?>" style="cursor:pointer" />
</div>
<div id="thevideo" style="display:none">
    <?php echo $videoEmbed ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
echo '<div onclick="thevid=document.getElementById(\'thevideo\'); thevid.style.display=\'block\'; this.style.display=\'none\'">
         <img src="'.$postThumb.'" style="cursor:pointer" />
      </div>
      <div id="thevideo" style="display:none">"'.$videoEmbed.'"</div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `<?php ?>` around any php commands you are typing. try `<?php echo "whatever you want here"?>`